# How do you get and use data (logos) from R library (nflplotR) properly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, model

I've been trying to figure out how to pull logos from nflplotR and display them in the visual but can't seem to figure out how to do it properly. I'm fairly new to R, so I think there's some nuances I am not good with.

I tried to remove the "logos" variable and tried a different approach as well but had no luck. It might be the way I'm pulling the data from the library but not really sure. Any help would be appreciated.

```
library(nflfastR)
library(nflplotR)
library(tidyverse)
library(gghighcontrast)
library(scales)
library(ggimage)
library(ggthemes)

plot_for_data <-
  function(data,
           logos,
           foreground_color,
           background_color) {
    # NOTE: Doesn't work well with facet_wrap()...need to specify
    # team logos more dynamically based on the data being charted.
    
    single_game_id <- data[1, ]$game_id
    
    game_title_pieces <- strsplit(single_game_id, "_")[[1]]
    game_year <- game_title_pieces[1]
    game_week <- game_title_pieces[2]
    
    # Get home_team and away_team and annotate on chart
    home_team_abbr <- data[1, ]$home_team
    away_team_abbr <- data[1, ]$away_team
    
    # Build a data frame with coordinates of team logo to place on chart
    logo_placement_data <- data.frame(
      a = c(3600, 3600),
      b = c(0.875, 0.125),
      team_abbr = c(home_team_abbr, away_team_abbr),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    ) %>% inner_join(logos, by = "team_abbr")
    
    #ggplot(logo_placement_data, aes(x = a, y = b)) +
    #  geom_nfl_logos(aes(team_abbr = c(home_team_abbr, away_team_abbr), alpha = alpha, colour = colour), width = 0.075) +
    #  geom_label(aes(label = teams), nudge_y = -0.35, alpha = 0.5) +
    #  scale_alpha_identity() +
    #  scale_color_identity() +
    #  theme_void()
    
    plot <- ggplot(data,
                   aes(x = game_seconds_remaining, y = home_wp_custom)) +
      # 50% reference line
      geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5,
                 color = grey,
                 size = 1) +
      
      # Reference line for each quarter (and halftime)
      geom_vline(xintercept = 15 * 60, color = grey) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = 30 * 60, color = grey) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = 45 * 60, color = grey) +
      
      annotate(
        "text",
        x = 58 * 60,
        y = 0.95,
        label = "Q1",
        family = "InputMono",
        color = grey,
        size = 2
      ) +
      annotate(
        "text",
        x = 43 * 60,
        y = 0.95,
        label = "Q2",
        family = "InputMono",
        color = grey,
        size = 2
      ) +
      annotate(
        "text",
        x = 28 * 60,
        y = 0.95,
        label = "Q3",
        family = "InputMono",
        color = grey,
        size = 2
      ) +
      annotate(
        "text",
        x = 13 * 60,
        y = 0.95,
        label = "Q4",
        family = "InputMono",
        color = grey,
        size = 2
      ) +
      
      # Win Probability
      geom_line(aes(y = home_wp_post), color = grey) +
      geom_line(size = 0.8) +
      
      # Scoring events
      geom_rug(
        data = filter(data, away_scoring_play == 1),
        color = foreground_color,
        sides = "b",
        size = 1.5
      ) +
      geom_rug(
        data = filter(data, home_scoring_play == 1),
        color = foreground_color,
        sides = "t",
        size = 1.5
      ) +
      
      # Draw home and away team logo
      geom_image(
        data = logo_placement_data,
        aes(x = x, y = y, image = logos),
        size = 0.08,
        asp = 16 / 9
      ) +
      
      # Formatting
      scale_x_reverse() +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = percent, limits = c(0, 1)) +
      theme_high_contrast(
        base_family = "InputMono",
        background_color = background_color,
        foreground_color = foreground_color
      ) +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
            axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
      labs(
        title = str_interp(
          "${game_year} Week ${game_week}: ${away_team_abbr} at ${home_team_abbr}"
        ),
        subtitle = "Custom win probability model compared to nflfastR WP (grey)",
        caption = "Data from nflfastR",
        x = "Quarters",
        y = "Home Win Probability"
      )
  }

for (single_game_id in game_ids) {
  plot <-
    plot_for_data(
      filter(pbp_data, game_id == single_game_id),
      logos,
      foreground_color,
      background_color
    )
  
  ggsave(
    str_interp("wp-${single_game_id}.png"),
    plot = plot,
    width = 6,
    height = 4
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `nflplotR::geom_nfl_logos` function instead of `geom_image`. Check out [this vignette](https://nflplotr.nflverse.com/articles/nflplotR.html) for different examples of how to add logos to your ggplot.

Based on your code, this should work:

```
ggplot(logo_placement_data, aes(x = a, y = b)) +
    geom_nfl_logos(aes(team_abbr = team_abbr), width = 0.075) +
    geom_label(aes(label = teams), nudge_y = -0.35, alpha = 0.5) +
    scale_alpha_identity() +
    scale_color_identity() +
    theme_void()
```